# Accessing nested buckets in S3 with Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I know the path of the bucket I want to access `/bucket1/bucket2/etc/` but I can't figure out how to access it via boto3.

I can enumerate all buckets starting from the source, but can't get to the bucket I want.

For example I can do:

```
prod_bucket = s3.Bucket('prod')
```

But I cannot do:

```
prod_bucket = s3.Bucket('prod/prod2/')
```

TIA

Comment: You're using the wrong terminology. The bucket is the entry point aka the flat name space. How about just `aws s3 ls s3://'prod/prod2/'` from the CLI

Comment: Sure it works fine in the CLI, but doesn't work the same as boto3/python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no nested buckets. You have bucket and objects.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
object = s3.get_object(Bucket='prod', Key='prod2/..')
```

Or:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('prod')
object = bucket.Object('prod2/..')
```

See: [get_object](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object)

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I get a "botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey". Even though I've double checked the names/keys are correct.